# Method locateStructure of the ServerWorld class returning null

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

For a Fabric mod, I am making an item that locates the nearest Nether Fortress on its use:

```
@Override
public TypedActionResult<ItemStack> use(World world, PlayerEntity user, Hand hand) {
    if (!world.isClient) {

        ServerPlayerEntity player = (ServerPlayerEntity) user;
        ServerWorld serverWorld = player.getWorld();

        TagKey<ConfiguredStructureFeature<?, ?>> tagKey = TagKey.of(Registry.CONFIGURED_STRUCTURE_FEATURE_KEY, Registry.STRUCTURE_FEATURE.getId(StructureFeature.FORTRESS));
        System.out.println(serverWorld.locateStructure(tagKey, player.getBlockPos(), 1000, false)); 
    }
    user.getStackInHand(hand).decrement(1);
    return TypedActionResult.consume(user.getStackInHand(hand));
}
```

However, I have attempted to figure out how to use the `locateStructure` method for a while now, but I have yet to be able to get a result that does not return `null`.

I understand that the `locateStructure` method in the `ServerWorld` class uses the `locateStructure` method in the `ChunkGenerator` class which passes a `RegistryEntryList` from the structure's `TagKey` after using the `get` method as an `Optional`.

The main issue I have found is in getting an `Optional` of the Nether Fortress `TagKey` that doesn't just return `Optional.empty`.

```
serverWorld.getRegistryManager().get(Registry.CONFIGURED_STRUCTURE_FEATURE_KEY)
```

returns

```
Registry[ResourceKey[minecraft:root / minecraft:worldgen/configured_structure_feature] (Stable)]
```

and then

```
serverWorld.getRegistryManager().get(Registry.CONFIGURED_STRUCTURE_FEATURE_KEY).getEntryList(tagKey)
```

returns `Optional.empty` despite using the Fortress `TagKey` and getting the `Registry` of the configured structure feature.

Having said that, how would you go about using the locateStructure method without it returning null or is there another way to locate the coordinates of a structure?

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am at a genuine loss.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow ! What is your exact question ?

Comment: How would you go about using the locateStructure method without it returning null or is there another way to locate the coordinates of a structure?